# SQLite, convert values 1 and 0 to values read and not read

Tags: sqlite

I have a table, with a column( called origin) containing values 1 and 0.

Is it possible to create a query in sqlite to convert these values on the fly?
Something like select origin ( convert 1 to read, 0 to not read) from table?

Thanx in advance.

Frits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select case when origin = 1 
            then 'read'
            else 'not read'
       end as origin
from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with a [CASE expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case):

```
SELECT CASE origin
       WHEN 1 THEN 'read'
       WHEN 0 THEN 'not read'
       ELSE        'whatever'  -- optional
       END
FROM MyTable
```